# legend in a plot using flot jquery api

Tags: java, jquery, plot, flot

I'm trying to modify a plot in order to insert a custom legend.
The code is the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    graph = $('.Graph').plot(formatFlotData(), {
    colors: [ '#20f', '#00ff4b', '#f00', '#fdff00'],
    xaxis: {
        show: false,
        min : 0,
        max : res
    },
    yaxis: {
        min : -50,
        max : 50,
        font : {
                    size: 11,
                    lineHeight: 13,
                    style: "italic",
                    weight: "bold",
                    family: "sans-serif",
                    variant: "small-caps",
                    color: "#f2f2f2"
                },
        color : "#f2f2f2"
    },
    grid: {
        borderColor : "#333",
        borderWidth : 3
    }
}).data("plot");
```

});

The html is:

```
<div class='Graph' style="display : inline-block"></div>
<div id="legend-container"></div>
```

The problem is no matter where i try to insert the "legend:" declaration, it doesn't seem to work.
I've tried right below the grid declaration and with a comma after the "}" right before the ")" of the plot function.

```
{legend: { show: true, container: '#legend-container' }}
```

Answer is:

```
var options = {
legend: {
    show: true,     
    position: "ne",     
    //backgroundColor: "#fdff00",
    backgroundOpacity: "0",
    margin: [-50,0]
    //container: null or jQuery object/DOM element/jQuery expression
}, ecc
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    graph = $('.Graph').plot(formatFlotData(),options).data("plot");
});
```

Comment: The `container` option needs to be a jQuery object/DOM element/jQuery expression, not a string - `$('#legend-container')` should work.

Comment: @mechenbier Not true, `'#legend-container'` is enough. It counts as a jQuery expression.

Answer (score 0):

The `container` option needs to be a [jQuery object/DOM element/jQuery expression](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-legend):

```
legend: {
    show: true,
    container: $('#legend-container')
}
```

This [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/19hm7x69/) has a working example.

Comment: in my case that wasnt enough i had to add an options var (see question)

Comment: `'#legend-container'` is enough, see his [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/19hm7x69/1/).